# R Matrix process with conditional additions

Tags: r, matrix

I have to pre-process a big matrix. To make my example easier to understand I will use the following matrix:

## Raw data

[image]

Where col = people and row = skills

In R my matrix is:

```
test <- matrix(c(18,12,15,0,13,0,14,0,12),ncol=3, nrow=3)
```

## Aim

In my case I need to process row by row. So there is 3 steps. For each row I have to :

1. Put 0 if ij=ij (So all diagonals equals zero)
2. Put 0 if one of the ij=0
3. Otherwise I have to add ij+ij

I will show the 3 steps to be more clear.

## Step 1 (row1)

The data are the row 1

[image]

The result is:

[image]

## Step 2 (row2)

The data are the row 2

[image]

The result is:

[image]

## Step 3 (row3)

The data are the row 3

[image]

The result is:

[image]

## Create a maximum matrix

Then the maximum matching are :

[image]

So my final matrix should be:

[image]

## Question

Can someone tell me how to succeed to achieve this in R? 
And of course the same process should work if my matrix has more row and columns...

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your latex is not rendering. I guess StackOverflow doesn't support it. :(

Comment: @Frank I initially posted on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ in order to render my latex code possible. And I don't know why someone moved my post to the basic stackoverflow.com who is not accepting latex code cuz don't have the matjax js included. Well can someone move my post back to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ? I think that my post is appropiated for http://stats.stackexchange.com/... Or do I have to put images instead my code?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the migration. The question does seem better for SO than stats to me, so I doubt they'll move it back. I can see that it would be a lot of work to make the question readable here, though.

Comment: @Frank quite disapointing that stackoverflow not have latex math render. Whatever I will spend my time to put everthing into png images ASAP (about 4h later from now)

Comment: You could also learn how to enter code here: just indent by four spaces or use the **{ }** button at the top of the editor box. Code is better, since we can copy-paste and try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my implementation in `R`. The code doesn't execute the steps exactly in the way you specified them. I focused on your final matrix and assumed that this is the main result you're interested in.

```
test <- matrix(c(18,12,15,0,13,0,14,0,12),ncol=3, nrow=3)

rownames(test) <- paste("Skill", 1:dim(test)[1], sep="")
colnames(test) <- paste("People", 1:dim(test)[2], sep="")

test

# Pairwise combinations 

comb.mat <- combn(1:dim(test)[2], 2)

pairwise.mat <- data.frame(matrix(t(comb.mat), ncol=2))
pairwise.mat$max.score <- 0

names(pairwise.mat) <- c("Person1", "Person2", "Max.Score")


for ( i in 1:dim(comb.mat)[2] ) { # Loop over the rows

    first.person <- comb.mat[1,i]
    second.person <- comb.mat[2,i]

    temp.mat <- test[, c(first.person, second.person)]

    temp.mat[temp.mat == 0] <- NA

    temp.rowSums <- rowSums(temp.mat, na.rm=FALSE)

    temp.rowSums[is.na(temp.rowSums)] <- 0

    max.sum <- max(temp.rowSums)

    previous.val <- pairwise.mat$Max.Score[pairwise.mat$Person1 == first.person & pairwise.mat$Person2 == second.person]

    pairwise.mat$Max.Score[pairwise.mat$Person1 == first.person & pairwise.mat$Person2 == second.person] <- max.sum*(max.sum > previous.val)


}

pairwise.mat

  Person1 Person2 Max.Score
1       1       2        25
2       1       3        32
3       2       3         0

person.mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(test)[2], ncol=dim(test)[2])
rownames(person.mat) <- colnames(person.mat) <- paste("People", 1:dim(test)[2], sep="")

diag(person.mat) <- 0

person.mat[cbind(pairwise.mat[,1], pairwise.mat[,2])] <- pairwise.mat$Max.Score


person.mat[lower.tri(person.mat, diag=F)] <- t(person.mat)[lower.tri(person.mat, diag=F)]


person.mat

        People1 People2 People3
People1       0      25      32
People2      25       0       0
People3      32       0       0
```

Comment: Thanks 1000 times to you. It is exactely what I was looking for ;) :-D

Comment: actually i face an Issue. When I write for  instance `test  <- matrix(c(17,13,11,0,0,0,10,0,10,0,15,14,15,8,11,13,0,15,0,11,13,10,0,0,0,0,14,0,0,12,16,0,0,0,0,0,12,18,0,18
), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE)` I get an issue because for instance when I write `pairwise.mat` I see person 1 and person 5 get a max score of 25 which is OK. But then `person.mat` shows a score of 24 in the matrix?? I think something is wrong after the loop ? Thanks.

Comment: Instead 'person.mat[lower.tri(person.mat)] <- person.mat[upper.tri(person.mat)]' I wrote 'person.mat[cbind(pairwise.mat[,2], pairwise.mat[,1])] <- pairwise.mat$Max.Score' It works. Thank you ;)

Comment: @Swiss12000 Glad I could help. You're right, the last matrix is not symmetrical. I've changed the code, now it works!

Comment: With your code I could learn lot of new techinques. Especially with the loop. I have another questinon. I use Rstudio and I want to know If I can run the loop many times in order to see all the steps (all loops + innercode). In r studio by default the loop runs fully (not step by step)

Comment: @Swiss12000 The use of RStudio has nothing to do with how R runs the loops, RStudio is just an excellent editor (I use it too). To see all the intermediate steps within the loop, just add `print()` to the loops and let it print out the steps that you want to see. For example: `print(temp.rowSums)` to see all sums of the combination.